# Call different function for each list item

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

And a list of functions like this:

```
[a, b, c, d]
```

Is there an easy way to get this output? Something like `zip`, but with functions and arguments?

```
[a(1), b(2), c(3), d(4)]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `zip()` and a list comprehension to apply each function to their paired argument:

```
arguments = [1, 2, 3, 4]
functions = [a, b, c, d]

results = [func(arg) for func, arg in zip(functions, arguments)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> def a(i): return 'function a: {}'.format(i)
...
>>> def b(i): return 'function b: {}'.format(i)
...
>>> def c(i): return 'function c: {}'.format(i)
...
>>> def d(i): return 'function d: {}'.format(i)
...
>>> arguments = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> functions = [a, b, c, d]
>>> [func(arg) for func, arg in zip(functions, arguments)]
['function a: 1', 'function b: 2', 'function c: 3', 'function d: 4']
```

Comment: You're a force of nature.

Comment: Would a list comprehension perform better than the `map` alternative below? `map(lambda func, arg: func(arg), functions, arguments)` is arguably a little more succinct and pythonic.

Comment: @nathancahill:  I disagree that that is more succint and pythonic. I find a list comprehension to be more readable, personally. The `lambda` adds another stack push, the two approaches will perform about the same, I think. I'll run a test.

Comment: @nathancahill: the list comprehension is *marginally* faster, but I'd call this too close to call, really. 1 million repetitions gives me `1.9220080375671387` for the list comp and `1.9732530117034912` for the `map()` approach.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @martijn-pieters. I'll stick with the list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

```
arguments = [1, 2, 3, 4]
functions = [a, b, c, d]

def process(func, arg):
    return func(arg)

results = map(process, functions, arguments)
```

define a function `process` to do the job, and use `map` to iterate the `functions` with its `arguments`

Comment: Ooh, nice! Even more succinctly: `map(lambda func, arg: func(arg), functions, arguments)`